# How to fix Form.control input width which changes when input type changes from "text" to "type"?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

On page load, input has `type = "text"` as I want to display placeholder text. I have added functionality on input that, on focus, input type should be `type = "time"`.

However, while changing to `type =" time"` width of input also changes. I want to keep the width same as it was on `input = "text"`.

Here is my code:

```
this.state = {type: 'text'}; 

onFocus() {this.setState({ type: 'time' });}
onBlur() {this.setState({type: 'text'});

<Form.Group>
       <Form.Label >From</Form.Label>
       <Form.Control type={this.state.type} onFocus={this.onFocus} onBlur={this.onBlur} placeholder="Shop opens" />
</Form.Group>
```

Comment: your questions is unclear please describe more

Comment: on page load, input has type = "text" as I want to display placeholder text. I have added functionality on input that, on focus, input type should be type = "time". But while changing to type =" time" width of input also changes. I want to keep the width same as it was on input = "text".

Comment: Please edit your question again without removing code formatting. Format your new information properly.

Comment: formatted, please check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add below css rule in your scss or css file which will control your
>   input width at any point of time :

```
custom-input-width {
  width : 250px !important; // you can set as per your requirement
}
```

> Apply this css rule on your input in react :

```
<input className="custom-input-width" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) . I fixed the problem, it's due to Form width was changing onClick and so it's components width were also changing.